# Scala - update HTML page after formsubmit

Tags: html, scala, playframework-2.0

I have to make a small scala-project for a job application on my university.

The user can enter a number in a form, then a scala function calculates a new number, then the html page has to show this number. I've got the input and calculation part figured out. How can i let Scala tell the HTML page to update? Or do i have to open a complete new page?

My code:

```
HTML
<form method="post" autocomplete="on">
    Your number here:<br>
    <input type="text" name="number" required="required" pattern="\d*">
    <input type="submit" value="Bereken">
</form>

Scala
val form = Form(
    "number" -> nonEmptyText
)

def submit = Action { implicit request =>
    val (number) = form.bindFromRequest.get
    **Some calculation here**
    **How do i tell my HTML page to update?**
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The page should be rendered in a controller.

the easiest solution for you is to render the tmeplate again via a controller, for instance:

```
//view is the name of the scala.html file
protected def openSpace(number:Int) =
     val newNumber = calculateNewNumber(number) 
    Ok(view(newNumber))
```

Or am I missing something?